# How to change computer name for local shared folder Windows 7

Tags: shared-directory

Hi Everyone i have a question regarding my own host file that impacts my shared folder name.

127.0.0.1 JEC

I place this in my host file without other IP sharing my local host.
And i would like to access the shared folder by
//JEC/SharedFolderName/Something

When I tried my Computer name and also localhost itself it passed through without any password prompt.
However when i wanted to try for //JEC/SharedFolderName/Something it just keep prompting for password. Despite keying the correct password it would throw an error message saying password is wrong.

I am using windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 0):

**To add new name**

Go to
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\

Open the file `Hosts` in notepad and add below line and save it.

> 127.0.0.1 JEC

**Disable password protected sharing**

Go to Control Panel

If Control Panel View by is Category

> Network and Internet--> Network and Sharing Center--> Change advanced sharing settings--> Under Password protected sharing--> Select "Turn off password protected sharing"

If Control Panel View by is Large icons/Small icons

> Go to Control Panel--> Network and Sharing Center--> Change advanced sharing settings--> Under Password protected sharing--> Select "Turn off password protected sharing"

Comment: Tried not working still prompt for password maybe a windows 7 problem

Comment: Have you turned off password protected sharing for all network profiles (Home or work, public, All networks)?